# Boundary of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Does it make sense to talk about boundary of a metric space, not of subset?

For example, if $E$ is the metric space consisting of the closed interval $ [ 0,1] $ with the usual metric of $\mathbb{R}$, then is $ \{0,1 \}$ the boundary points of $E$?

I kinda think not, since a boundary point of a set A is defined to be the point where any neighborhood of that point contain some point in A and some point not in A.  But in my example above, any neighborhood of the point $0$ and $1$ only contain point in $E$.

I'm new to topology so can anyone enlighten me about this? thank you very much.

**Update:** Thank you guys for all your answer, it really helps alot.  So let me state what I understand about manifold and can you guys correct me if I'm wrong??

I don't know much about general manifold but I only know Euclidean manifold thru the text of Munkres's Analysis on Manifold.
When we say a 1-manifold in $\mathbb{R^3}$, we mean a continuous curve in $\mathbb{R^3}$, is that correct?

let this curve be defined by $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R^3}$, and $f$ is a homeomorphism, then by what you guys just state the points $ x_1 = f(0) $ would be a boundary point since for any neighborhood $U$ of $x_1$, there is a neighborhood of the point $0$ that is open in $ \mathbb{H^1}= \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \geq 0 \}$ that maps homeomorphismly to $U$.

Is that correct? thank you for all your input.

Comment: @PHPirate Keep in mind that I'm taking the metric space $E$ to be only the set $ [0,1]$.  I'm not taking $E$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Now any neighborhood of the point $0$ say $ U(0,\delta)$ is defined by $ (0 - \delta, 0 + \delta) \cap E $.

Comment: Oops didn't read careful enough, my bad (comment removed)

Comment: @almagest That is a good insight, what do you mean by total ordering from $\mathbb{R}$?  Can you clarify that for me??

Comment: I don't have any particular answer for the general case, but one thought is that the "boundary" of a whole space can *sometimes* be defined topologically. For instance, $0$ and $1$ are special in the metric space $[0,1]$, as they are the only points not having any neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. This observation goes towards defining a manifold with boundary.

Comment: In the standard topological sense, the boundary of any metric space will be the null set, simply by definition, because the whole space must coincide with both its closure and its interior, whatever topology its equipped with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "kinda think not" is correct, but so is your intuition that the unit interval should have the points $0$ and $1$ on its boundary.

The structure you want to make this idea work is a manifold. It's a metric space plus some other stuff that makes it resemble a part of $\mathbb{R}^n$ without necessarily being embedded there.

The "manifold with boundary" paragraphs on this wikipedia page 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary 
describe what you need.

Comment: That is right for the general case, but is surely overkill for this special case?

Comment: @almagest Yes, you can do this special case without the manifold machinery but I think the reference to more advanced material addresses the OP's geometric intuition. Why not post your comment as an alternative correct answer?

Comment: in the middle of trying to do that!

Comment: @EthanBolker, I just edit and update my question, is this what you meant, Ethan??

Comment: @Khoata I think not quite. The wikipedia page shows how to define the boundary of a manifold-with-boundary without having to think of it as embedded in some larger Euclidean space. So the unit interval is a 1-manifold-with-boundary all by itself, independent of any view of it as part of the real line or as a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I see what you meant, but for manifold embedded in Euclidean space, then is it the correct interpretation?? Thank you.

Comment: @Khoata It's still tricky. If you embed a curve nicely in space all points of the image are boundary points in the topological sense, although not in the manifold sense. Folks have worked hard to get the right definitions, so learn them and use them. But keep thinking intuitively, too.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for your input.  It helps quite a bit.

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that the notion of "boundary" for a "manifold-with-boundary" is a different one than that of the boundary of a subset of a metric/topological space. Considering $[0,1]$ as a metric space by itself, it has no topological boundary, but it does have a boundary as a manifold-with-boundary (i.e., the endpoints). Of course, if you embed this into a larger space (e.g, $\mathbb R$), you will get that the corresponding notions of boundary coincide.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly if you regard $E$ as embedded in $\mathbb{R}$, then it has a boundary. But from your comments, I assume you are regarding $E$ as not embedded.

In that case, it is trivial that $E$ is open and closed and hence has no boundary (given the usual definitions - there is a [good Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) on the detail).

But if you are interested in the intuitive concept of boundary as "being on the periphery", rather than the usual definition, then you could still define the boundary in terms of the total ordering inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. In other words you take the boundary to be points $x\in E$ such that there do not exist points $x',x''$ with $x'<x<x''$, where $<$ is the ordering inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ (and points where $x',x''$ do exist are interior points).

Of course, it depends on what your intuitive concept is. If you regard it as *separating* $E$ from non-$E$, then it is hard to see how $E$ can have a boundary, and so the usual definition gives the result you want.

Note that this approach of using an inherited order does not generalise well to higher dimensions. If you want to generalise the idea of "being on the periphery" to other cases like subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you are better off using the machinery of manifold with boundary (also dealt with well on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary)). See also the answer by @EthanBolker .